# AngularJS - Ng-Table won't parse headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

Using Ng-table, I have tried to create one table view, that could be controlled from AngularJS parameters.

To control the header text, I need to put it in data-title or ng-data-title (Example: data-title="'Test'")

But, it always makes the table header empty.
[image]

Instead of filling it:
[image]

Code Snippet:

```
<td ng-repeat="v in tableSettings.data" data-title="v.name">
    {{v.data?v.data(row):row[v.id]}}
</td>
```

Full Code:

```
<table ng-table="table" class="table" show-filter="{{tableSettings.filter}}">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td ng-repeat="v in tableSettings.data" ng-click="tableSettings.click(row)" ng-attr-data-title="'{{v.name}}'"
            ng-if="v.type!='switch'"
            sortable="'{{sortable?sortable:v.id}}'">
            {{v.data?v.data(row):row[v.id]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table
```

When I try to parse Angular into it, I just get errors: (press to see the errors)

["'{{v.name}}'"](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%200-9%20[%27%7B%7Bv.name]&p2=%27%7B%7Bv.name)        ["{{v.name}}"](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bv.name&p4=%7Bv.name)

Is there a way to fix it, or even to parse it manualy from AngularJS?

Comment: I don't think you have pasted the relevant HTML where the error occurs.

Comment: Try using `ng-attr-data-title` instead.

Comment: ng-attr-data-title does nothing for the table. Which code would be more relevant?

Comment: Where is the part where you use ng-table?

Comment: @Arg0n I added the full table code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the problem is that the `data-title` attribute is meant to be used with static text (well known columns) such as `data-title="'My first column'"`
If what you need is dynamic columns you got to use the `ng-table-dynamic` directive.

For example:

```
<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in $data track by row.id">
    <td ng-repeat="col in $columns">{{::row[col.field]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Take notice in the directive declaration uses a special syntax `tablePrams` `with` `cols`. Here the cols is a `$scope` variable that must follow the following schema for this to work properly.

```
$scope.cols =  [
    { title: 'ID', field: 'id', filter: { id : 'text' }, show: true, sortable: 'id' }, 
    { title: 'Installation', field: 'installationAt' },
    ...
];
```

Title and field are mandatory whereas `filter`, `show`, `sortable` depend on your usage scenario.

You can play around with this [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaNayL?editors=101)

Comment: This is amazing! Its been over 2 months since I asked this question on the github "issues" thread. Thank you so much!